# With ReactVR, are you able to use a live camera feed for the VideoPano?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-360

https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/videopano.html

I would like to make this support Augmented Reality.  Is that possible with this library?

There are other libraries out there such as ar.js, but those required WebRTC, which is a showstopper since not supported on iOS.

Comment: don't think so. getUserMedia is anyway native function. Hope to find alternative until you are into native solution.

Comment: With A-frame it's easier see this: https://medium.com/arjs/augmented-reality-in-10-lines-of-html-4e193ea9fdbf

Comment: yeah, but that uses ar.js which needs WebRTC

Comment: FYI, ar.js now will be functional with the upcoming iOS11 update.  :)